# checking Looking for kernel source or headers in /usr/src/kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.el6.i686... configure: error: not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos

i m begginer i linux

i m installing libnetfilter-queue in Centos 6.3
 inspite of kernel-devel being installed i m getting following error.

on running 
./configure

i m getting following error at the end

checking Looking for kernel source or headers in 2.6.32-279.el6.i686...
checking Looking for kernel source or headers in 2.6.32-279.el6.i686/include...
checking Looking for kernel source or headers in /usr/src/linux-2.6.32-279.el6.i686...
checking Looking for kernel source or headers in /usr/src/kernel-2.6.32-279.el6.i686...
checking Looking for kernel source or headers in /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-279.el6.i686...
checking Looking for kernel source or headers in /usr/src/kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.el6.i686...
configure: error: not found

please tell the solution in detail

Answer (score 0):

Its looking for the linux kernel headers which is possibly not available on you system. This is require for building netfilter.

First, check if its already installed with command:
`rpm -qa | grep kernel`

Next step would be to determine the correct version of headers and installing it:

`yum install kernel-headers-2.6.32-279`

hope this helps!